# React redux value inside a function of a functional component returns the value a cycle late

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-redux, expo, react-hooks

I recently changed my code from class components to functional components and using hooks. However, I ran into a problem where the accessing a redux value using `useSelector` and `useDispatch`.

```
let started = useSelector((state: any) => state.routines.started)
const dispatch = useDispatch()
```

The value that I retrieve from useSelector works, however, when accessing this value inside a function, the value of started only returns its previous expected value. Only after the second rerender that the value of started changes to its expected value.

Say I have this button code

```
<Button onPress={() => startRoutine()}>Start routine</Button>
```

And the startRoutine function

```
let startRoutine = () => {
        dispatch(startRoutineAction())
        console.log(`started (startRoutine Home): ${started}`);
        if(started){
            ...START CODE

        } else {
            ...STOP CODE
        }
}
```

I expect that after dispatching the startRoutineAction() method, the value of started becomes changes true to false. However, I get *`false`* after logging it in the startRoutine function. 
The strange part is that I get *`true`* when I log it outside the startRoutine function like this. This is still within the function component

```
console.log(started)
return (
    ...VIEW CODE
)
```

I noticed then that although the actions are being dispatched properly, the values accessed from within the startRoutine function are being accessed a cycle late. This can be seen in a counter, where I'm logging the current count after dispatching an addCount() function

```
let addCount = () => {
    dispatch(addCount())
    console.log(`count: ${count}`);
}
```

If the value of count starts at 0. Then the first time the addCount function is run, it will return the count value of 0, even though the expected value should be 1

I'm using the following package versions

- expo ^35.0.0
- react-redux ^7.1.1
- redux-persist ^5.10.0.

Answer (score 1):

In Redux as soon as an `Action` is dispatched it doesn't update the store immediately it will call the reducer with the action and the current state, it won't wait till the reducer is finished updating the state and in the meantime, your next statement is executed.
So the value does get updated but you get the previous state in your `console` statement.

You can check this [doc](https://redux.js.org/basics/data-flow/).

Comment: Hi, I did think about this, however, when I set a timeout function to wait 1-3 seconds after executing the dispatch function, the result is still the same. How can I force my application to wait for the dispatch function?

Comment: I see that you have an if statement so rather than executing the right after the dispatch you could use `useEffect`

Comment: Isn't useEffect used for react lifecycle methods like componentDidMount and the like?

Comment: yeah, you can just set up a `useEffect` for just `started` property so it will be called whenever the `started` property changed.